# How create customs cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code, i tried of create customs cell but i get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
>       reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Why do I get that error? what is bad in my code?

```
  if( "1" == (typeCell!)){
            var nib = UINib(nibName: "CreateA", bundle:nil);
            tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"CreateA");
            cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CreateA", for: indexPath) as! CreateA
        }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code but it seems there is no `CreateAccountCell.xib` file in your application.

Comment: @Sulthan i programming all with code, i do not use storyboard

Comment: Well, you are trying to load a xib (not storyboard). A nib is a compiled xib file. Maybe you should register a class instead?

Comment: I don't think registering nibs are allowed there. Even if it is, it's a very bad practice.

Comment: @Desdenova It is allowed. I actually use it in a `UITableView` extension to automatically register nibs. `UINib` is just a file name so there is no big performance overhead reregistering.

Comment: @Sulthan I use something similar as well, but not in the data source method just before dequeuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you don't have any xibs, you probably want to register the class itself:

```
tableView.register(CreateAccountCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"CreateAccountCell");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you rename files outside of XCode. To solve it you can just remove the files from your project (Right Click - Delete and "Remove Reference").

Then after you can re-import the files in your project and everything will be OK.